# c# Unable to get Winform Progress Bar to Animate Error Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

New to c#. I have a winform with a combobox, button and progress bar. On the button click event text is taken from the textbox and used in a sql query. While this query is running, I would like a progress bar (marquee - does not need to show % complete) to animate, when the query is complete I would like it to stop.
I have tried the below code but get the error:

> 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cbTest' accessed from a
> thread other than the thread it was created on.'.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar _progressBar;

public Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _progressBar = progressBar;
}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    _progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}

public async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => GetValues(_progressBar));
}

private void GetValues(System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    progressBar.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
    }));

    Sql.SqlQuery("exec Test..sp_Test " + cbTest.Text);

    progressBar.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
    }));
}

public static void SqlQuery(string queryString, string connectionString = "Data Source= Test; Initial Catalog = Test; Integrated Security = True")
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.CommandTimeout = 300;
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What is this assignment `_progressBar = progressBar;`? Where does `progressBar` come from? 2) `GetValues` is `void` thus cannot be awaited. It should be a `Task` that returns data in some data container (`DataTable`, `List<>` ...etc.). Then you can access the UI elements (ProgressBar, ComboBox ..etc) before and after the `await ...`. 3) [mre].

Comment: Thank you. I initialize it at the very start of the code. progressBar is a ProgressBar1 on my userform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has got absolutely zero to do with the `ProgressBar`. Raed the error message. It says that you are accessing `cbTest` - the `ComboBox` - on the wrong thread. You obviously know that you have to access the `ProgressBar` on the UI thread. Why do you think it's OK to do otherwise for the `ComboBox`?

The solution would be to not access the `ComboBox` in that methopd at all. Change that method to accept a `string` as well and then get the `Text` from the `ComboBox` before creating the `Task` and pass that `string` in.

To be honest, I would do nothing but the query in that method. Do all the pre-query UI stuff first, then create the `Task` to perform the query`, passing in any data that is required. After the` Task` completes, do the post-query UI stuff.

Comment: That worked thank you, as regards passing the combo box in as a string to the method. If I wanted to have a data grid view on the same form that populated with the output of an sql query, from clicking that button, how would one do that. I tried doing it and got the cross thread error. I'm not understanding the thread logic, apologies.

Comment: I added this to the GetValues method ```dgv.Invoke(new Action(() => { Sql.SqlQuery("exec sp_Test", dgv); }));```, which worked, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it,

Comment: @CGarden, the comments on an answer to a question is not the place to ask a new question. Post a new question and include all and only the information that is relevant to that question. You can provide a link to this question for background if it adds value.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution that I wrote to answer my question, after using the advice from @jmcilhinney answer.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar _progressBar;
private string _comboBoxText;

public Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _progressBar = progressBar1;
}

private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    _progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}

public async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _comboBoxText = cbRegion.Text;

    _progressBar.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        _progressBar.Visible = true;
        _progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
    }));

    await Task.Run(() => RunSql(_comboBoxText));

    _progressBar.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        _progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        _progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        _progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        _progressBar.Visible = false;
    }));
}

private void RunSql(string region)
{
    Sql.SqlQuery("exec Test..sp_Test " + region);
}

public static void SqlQuery(string queryString, string connectionString = "Data Source= Test; Initial Catalog = Test; Integrated Security = True")
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.CommandTimeout = 300;
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```